# Updating values in real time Talend

Tags: real-time, talend

I'm trying to update my data with talend.I'm using tOracleOutput with the option 'update or insert' but my problem is that when there is an update i want to sum the older and the newer value of a row because my app is executing in real time.There is any help? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: i really need this response please

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tOracleRow component containing a SQL update statement . Take the new value (from context, row, or globalMap) and use that in the update statement within tOracleRow, adding it to the existing value of the desired record.

Ex 
"
UPDATE target_table
SET target_field = target_field " + globalMap.get("newVal") + "
WHERE target_id = " + globalMap.get("id") + "
"